# Getting error in MySQL delete command through java code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have used jdbc to delete records from the table, while eexcuting the same, I got an error as I have shown below :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2674)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2815)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultSet.java:236)
    at net.ordernet.vd.lookupTable.UpdateLookupTable.deleteLookupTableRecords(UpdateLookupTable.java:118)
    at net.ordernet.vd.soap.UpdateLookupTableTool.deleteLookupTableRecords(UpdateLookupTableTool.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
```

My code is as follows :
1) two strings are taken to specify the query
2) connection object is used to prepare statement
3) checked the result of update query in 'int' variable
4) I havent used the result-Set, getting the resultset exception though...!

```
try 
{
  String queryDeleteLookupTableRecords = "delete from LookupTableRecords where tableId = ?";
  String queryDeleteLookupTableRows = "delete from LookupTableRows where tableId = ?";

  PreparedStatement psDeleteLookupTableRecords = oConnection.prepareStatement(queryDeleteLookupTableRecords);
  PreparedStatement psDeleteLookupTableRows = oConnection.prepareStatement(queryDeleteLookupTableRows);
  psDeleteLookupTableRecords.setInt(1, oLookupTable.getID());
  psDeleteLookupTableRows.setInt(1, oLookupTable.getID());
  int result = psDeleteLookupTableRecords.executeUpdate();
  int result2 = psDeleteLookupTableRows.executeUpdate();
  if(result > 0 && result2 > 0)
  {
     iReturnValue = 1;
  }
  psDeleteLookupTableRecords.close();
  psDeleteLookupTableRows.close();
}
catch (SQLException oSqlException) 
{
  Log.print(oSqlException);
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace and code snippet don't seem to have any correlation. Could you post the code of the method `UpdateLookupTable.deleteLookupTableRecords()`? You're calling `getInt()` on a `ResultSet` there and it looks like you didn't call `rs.next()` before that.

Comment: It would help if you can pinpoint where exactly the exception occurs. And annotate the code in the question to show us.

Comment: @PhilippReichart, a `delete` statement does not return a resultset. And the code is **`setint`** not GETINT

Comment: @Johan I never said so -- the stacktrace obviously shows a `ResultSet` being involved somewhere in the OP's code, though, that's also where the `getInt()` is happening.

Comment: UpdateLookupTable.java:118 - what's there

Comment: @PhilippReichart, aha yes I see your point now. The exception occurs in some other code, definitely not in de code sample because the error involves a resultset. No wonder the OP is stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not in the code that you showed. You are having a `resultSet.getInt(..)` somewhere before calling `resultSet.first()` or `.next()`